# How to control computer fans with GPIO

Tags: gpio

I want to build a smart air conditioner with my Raspberry Pi 3b+ by using these PC Fans: https://www.amazon.de/Arctic-F12-PWM-PST-Geh%C3%A4usel%C3%BCfter/dp/B00NTUJTAK/ref=cm_wl_huc_item.

What is required to control these fans using the GPIO pins?

Comment: you are asking your question at the wrong time .... your first question should be `what control signal do these fans require?` .... when you know the answer, then ask your question

Answer (score 1):

You need no external circuitry to control it, just a 12V power supply.
You then connect the fan's pwm input to your gpio which has to generate a PWM at 25kHz (intel standard for pc fans). Keep common ground between the fan and the raspberry.